# Correct method to implement onCreate in android

Tags: java, android

My app crashes. I look throught most are using this approach public class MainActivity extends
where is the errors in this short code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

   radioGroup=findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    Button ok=findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new view.onClicklisenn){
        public void onClick(view view){
            int radioId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioButton=findViewById(radioId);
            textView.setText("choise"+radioButton.getText());

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi @benacerSalah where does it crash ??

Comment: What is the error message? We can't possibly know what's wrong with this code if we don't know what your app looks like? Maybe the components like radiobutton or textview can't be found... Maybe `view.onClicklisenn` is a typo.... This question needs more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your code if you have initialised all variables correctly

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               int radioId=radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
               radioButton=findViewById(radioId);
               textView.setText("choise"+radioButton.getText());

            }
          });
```

Comment: Th.nnnnnnnnnnnnx Dear

Comment: Welcome , which IDE u were using , wasn't it showing you errors , how you build the project